# lodash: combine array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, lodash

In lodash, I want to convert an array of objects to a single object that contains an array of each property.

I have an array of objects:

```
var students = [{
    name: 'A',
    idNo: 1,
    marks: {
        math: 98,
        sci: 97,
        eng: 89
    }
}, {
    name: 'B',
    idNo: 2,
    marks: {
        math: 88,
        sci: 87,
        eng: 79
    }
}, {
    name: 'C',
    idNo: 3,
    marks: {
        math: 87,
        sci: 98,
        eng: 91
    }
}]
```

I want to combine / reshape them like this:

```
{
    name: [A, B, C],
    idNo: [1, 2, 3],
    marks: [{
            math: 98,
            sci: 97,
            eng: 89
        }, {

            math: 88,
            sci: 87,
            eng: 79            
    }, {
            math: 87,
            sci: 98,
            eng: 91
        }
    }]
}
```

I want this to be done purely with lodash or js inbuilt functions without any loops.

Edit : I have already implemented a solution as suggested by Nenad. I want a utility function in lodash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use lodash's [**mapValues**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#mapValues) function:

```
var result = _.mapValues(students[0], (value, key) => _.map(students, key));
```

`mapValues` creates an object with the same keys as the object passed to it as the first parameter. Here we pass the first object in the students array `students[0]` so the object returned by `mapValues` will look something like this:

```
{
    name: ....,
    idNo: ....,
    marks: ....
}
```

The value for each key is determined by the function that is passed to `mapValues` as the second parameter. `mapValues` will call this function for each key and pass the value and the key. We're not interested in the value but the key is used to pluck all the values in the `student` array for that key (by calling [**map**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#map) with the key as the second parameter).

```js
var students = [{
    name: 'A',
    idNo: 1,
    marks: {
        math: 98,
        sci: 97,
        eng: 89
    }
}, {
    name: 'B',
    idNo: 2,
    marks: {
        math: 88,
        sci: 87,
        eng: 79
    }
}, {
    name: 'C',
    idNo: 3,
    marks: {
        math: 87,
        sci: 98,
        eng: 91
    }
}]


var result = _.mapValues(students[0], (value, key) => _.map(students, key));

document.getElementById('result').textContent = JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <pre id="result"></pre>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can merge all objects in the array to a new object using `_.mergeWith()` with the spread operator:

```js
const students = [{"name":"A","idNo":1,"marks":{"math":98,"sci":97,"eng":89}},{"name":"B","idNo":2,"marks":{"math":88,"sci":87,"eng":79}},{"name":"C","idNo":3,"marks":{"math":87,"sci":98,"eng":91}}];

const result = _.mergeWith({}, ...students, (objValue, srcValue) => 
  (objValue || []).concat(srcValue));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

In older browser's you can concat all parameters to a single array, and use [`_.spread()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#spread):

```js
var students = [{"name":"A","idNo":1,"marks":{"math":98,"sci":97,"eng":89}},{"name":"B","idNo":2,"marks":{"math":88,"sci":87,"eng":79}},{"name":"C","idNo":3,"marks":{"math":87,"sci":98,"eng":91}}];
                                          
var result = _.spread(_.mergeWith)([{}].concat(students, function(objValue, srcValue){
  return (objValue || []).concat(srcValue);
}));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce()` and `forEach()` to get desired result.

```js
var students = [{"name":"A","idNo":1,"marks":{"math":98,"sci":97,"eng":89}},{"name":"B","idNo":2,"marks":{"math":88,"sci":87,"eng":79}},{"name":"C","idNo":3,"marks":{"math":87,"sci":98,"eng":91}}];

var result = students.reduce(function(r, e) {
  Object.keys(e).forEach(function(k) {
    if (!r[k]) {
      r[k] = [];
    }
    r[k].push(e[k])
  })
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I should have mentioned this, but I have already used this. I want to know if lodash has a built-in functionality for this.

Answer (score 0):

You might do it with a single reduce;

```js
var students = [{
    name: 'A',
    idNo: 1,
    marks: {
        math: 98,
        sci: 97,
        eng: 89
    }
}, {
    name: 'B',
    idNo: 2,
    marks: {
        math: 88,
        sci: 87,
        eng: 79
    }
}, {
    name: 'C',
    idNo: 3,
    marks: {
        math: 87,
        sci: 98,
        eng: 91
    }
}],
     result = students.reduce((p,c) => (p.name.push(c.name), p.idNo.push(c.idNo), p.marks.push(c.marks), p), {name:[], idNo:[], marks:[]});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another lodash example with [`_.mergeWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#mergeWith)

```js
var students = [{ name: 'A', idNo: 1, marks: { math: 98, sci: 97, eng: 89 } }, { name: 'B', idNo: 2, marks: { math: 88, sci: 87, eng: 79 } }, { name: 'C', idNo: 3, marks: { math: 87, sci: 98, eng: 91 } }],
    result = {};

    _.forEach(students, v => _.mergeWith(result, v, (o, s) => !_.isArray(o) ? [s] : o.concat(s)));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another lodash example with [*.reduce(collection, [iteratee=*.identity], [accumulator])](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#reduce).

- `collection (Array|Object)`: The collection to iterate over.
- `[iteratee=_.identity] (Function)`: The function invoked per iteration.
- `[accumulator] (*)`: The initial value.

Code:

```js
var students = [{name: 'A', idNo: 1, marks: { math: 98, sci: 97, eng: 89}}, {name: 'B', idNo: 2, marks: { math:88,  sci: 87,  eng: 79}}, {name: 'C', idNo: 3, marks: { math: 87, sci: 98, eng: 91}}],
    obj = _.reduce(students, function(o, item) {
      o.name.push(item.name);
      o.idNo.push(item.idNo);
      o.marks.push(item.marks);
      return o;
    }, {name: [], idNo: [], marks: []});

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```